# Sortable jquery UI - Получить класс элемента, где было выполнено событие

Tags: jquery, классы, sortable

Добрый вечер!
Помогите разобраться, как получить класс элемента, где было выполнено событие stop (т.е. получить класс элемента куда мы перетащили).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('table tbody').sortable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        ???????????????????????
    }    
});
});
```

Comment: Можете поточнее сформулировать ваш вопрос? Вы из одного sortable-списка перетягиваете в другой?

Comment: Использую как drag and drop. Т.е. суть такова: есть таблица и есть несколько отдельных div за таблицей, у каждого свой class. Я перетягиваю строки tr из таблицы в блок, вот после события stop нужно узнать в какой блок перетащили tr.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("tbody").sortable({
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    var newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
$.get('request.php?f=products_images.sort&sort='+newOrder);
                }
            });
<tbody >
    <tr id="7298"></tr>
    <tr id="72498"></tr>
    <tr id="72398"></tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: @wmgodyak, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.